# Does the Rambam's definition of cofer Torah no longer hold?

Tags: rambam, sefer-torah

In hilchot teshuvah, perek 3, halacha 8, the Rambam writes that someone "who denies the Torah" is "one who says the Torah, or one verse, or one word is not from God".

Taking into consideration the differences between the Allepo Codex, the Leningrad codex, the Sephardic/ashkenaz Torah scroll and the Teimani scroll, can we still say that the Rambam's statement holds true?